# Find the general solution to the differential equation $y' + 12 x^{11} y = x^{12}$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$y' + 12 x^{11} y = x^{12}$

Use the variable $I = \int e^{x^{12}} dx$ where it occurs in your answer.

I attempted this one and found the variable $I$ also works as the integrating factor. Then I arrived at $ ye^{x^{12}} = \int x^{12} e^{x^{12}}dx $. I'm stuck here.

Comment: You cant express y with elementary functions unfortunately.

Comment: I think it is supposed to be expressed in terms of elementary functions and $I$, which itself cannot be expressed with elementary functions.

Answer (score 1):

You wish to simplify:

$$I_{2} = \int x^{12}e^{x^{12}}\ dx$$

Integrating by parts with $u = \frac{x}{12}, v = e^{x^{12}}$, so $v'= 12x^{11}e^{x^{12}}$:

$$I_{2} = \int uv'\ dx = uv - \int u'v \ dx$$

$$I_{2} = \frac{xe^{x^{12}}}{12} - \int\frac{e^{x^{12}}}{12}\ dx = \frac{xe^{x^{12}} - (I + C)}{12}$$

Thus:

$$y = \frac{I_{2}}{e^{x^{12}}} = \boxed{\frac{x}{12} - \frac{I}{e^{x^{12}}} + \frac{C}{e^{x^{12}}}}$$

Here, $C$ can be any constant so we do not need to show its negation or division by $12$.

Comment: In your set up for variable u: do you mean $u = x^{12}$ instead of $u = \frac{x}{12}$?

Comment: No, $u$ is set up so that $uv' = x^{12}e^{x^{12}}$. Did I make an error?

Answer (score 0):

This is linear ODE, its integrating factor is
$e^{x^{12}}$, then $$y=e^{-x^{12}}\int x^{12} e^{x^{12}} dx+Ce^{-x^{-12}}$$
$$y=e^{-x^{12}}\int x. x^{11} e^{x^{12}}dx+Ce^{-x^{-12}}$$
Integrate by parts
$$y=e^{-x^{12}}[x \frac{e^{x^{12}}}{12}-\int e^{x^{12}} dx]+C e^{-x^{12}}$$
$$y=\frac{x}{12}-e^{-x^{12}} ~\frac{x \Gamma[1/12,-x^{12}]}{{144(-x^{12})}^{1/12}}+C e^{-x^{12}}$$